# Как работает JIT-компилятор в .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, jit

В книге пишут, что при запуске программы она компилируется в машинных код из IL, и при каждом следующем до выключения компьютера или перезагрузки запуске программы будет запускаться уже скомпилированная программа, а иначе она заново из IL будет компилироваться в машинный код JIT-компилятором. Так ли это? Есть ли более подробная информация об этом процессе?

Comment: `CLR via C#` - Дж. Рихтер - более подробная информация. На вопрос "Так ли это?" ответ - it depends. Можно один раз сбилдить в машинный код для конкретной среды развертывания. Ещё очень много информации можно найти ту - [Книги по C# и другая литература](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0) в разделе `Книги для специалистов: внутренние механизмы и пыльные углы`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Когда среда CLR выполняет IL код, то происходит следующее: при вызове блока IL-кода JIT-компилятор проверяет и преобразует его в машинные команды которые он сохраняет в динамическом блоке памяти. Затем, он возвращается к структуре данных типа и заменяет адрес вызываемого метода адресом этого блока памяти и при следующем запросе повторная компиляция не будет выполнена, а будет использован уже скомпилированный код.

Теперь, непосредственно, **ответ на ваш вопрос**: нет, весь скомпилированный код хранится в динамической памяти, а это значит, что этот код уничтожается при выходе из приложения.

В тоже время, существует способ предварительной компиляции приложения в образ в машинном коде (Native Image) с помощью [Native Image Generator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6t9t5wcf(v=vs.110).aspx) (Ngen.exe)

Comment: Добавьте уж про NGen.exe,  я думаю полезно будет.

Comment: Что ты здесь подразумеваешь под структурой данных типа? Откуда она?

Comment: Под структурой данных тут понимается тип, а под «блоком IL-кода» метод этого типа.